# Chrome dev tools: temporary turn off events

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have complex SPA with component which performs some DOM manipulating when clicked.

How can I inspect DOM of this component with chrome dev tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on default) without raising any events (to see DOM before manipulations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right side of the developer console provides more controls. You can click on the DOM element you want then either choose "Event Listeners" to track the build in event listeners of the element (without you adding any listeners) or alternatively add DOM Breakpoints (by right clicking on the element and choosing when to break) and use the `DOM Breakpoints` option (on the right side menu).
Hope this helps

Comment: I saw it, but I cant realize 3 things:
1. How can i select element _before_ raising any events? Manually find element in dom without ctrl+shift+c is tricky when you have long and very complicated dom structure.
2. I dont want to _remove_ events, I want to temporary stop it _before_ they working. 
3. I want to stop _all_ events. Not manually 1 by 1. Is it possible?

Comment: DOM breakpoints can be userful, but can I prevent all code of handlers from execution, not just DOM manipulations? I think dom breakpoints is enough for me, but it is not very comfort anyway.

Comment: 1. Open the element inspector, CTRL+F to search for the DOM element, then refresh browser. This should give you the element before its events are raised. 2. A breakpoint will stop execution, so ideally you should set the breakpoint to be before the events for the element are executed. 3. Check if `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` might be of help to you